# How can I browse linux kernel package source like I can other packages on Launchpad?

Tags: kernel, package-management, launchpad

I want to go here https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux and see how the kernel is packaged. Specifically I think there may be an old debian patch still in there that is affecting my hardware.

e.g. https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libevent shows the branches for the various releases and I can choose a branch and browse files.

How can I do this for the Linux Kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ you will find ALL the kernels currently used. Select the one in question. You will find the "build.log" and the "changes" there.

Comment: follow up question is how do I map my ubuntu kernel version to the linux kernel version there?  3.5.0-19-generic there is no 3.5.0 at the link you posted.

Comment: I don't know. recommend asking 'as a question'